# Dynamically outputting array information after parsing information

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to parse through some defined font styles to create an array to use for determining what font styling to use in a document. Currently, I'm just displaying the information that's being stored in the array just to see if I'm getting it right, but I've noticed that it's storing the information statically, which isn't what I want.

This is the information I'm parsing through:

```
<!Font Definitions,
    F2 = Times 6,
    F3 = Times 10,
    F7 = Times 10 Bold,
    F8 = Times 9,
    F6 = Times 12,
    F9 = Symbols 12,
    F12 = Times 10 Italic,
    F13 = Helvetica 14 Bold,
    F15 = Times 12 Bold,
    F16 = Times 15,
    F17 = Times 14 Bold,
    F18 = Times 18 Bold,
    F25 = Times 6 Bold,
    F26 = Times 6 Italic,
    F27 = Times 21 Bold,
    F28 = Times 27 Bold,
    F30 = Times 15 Bold,
    F37 = Times 9 Bold,
    F38 = Times 9 Italic>
```

I've tried two different times to get the output that I want. This was the first attempt:

*Note: the `text.jor.ildoc` file is a QuickSilver file. The information I'm parsing works the same if you were to put it into a text document instead.

```
public class Test {

    private class FontF {
        private String FontID;
        private String FontFamily;
        private String FontSize;
        private String FontAttribute;
    }

    Test test = new Test();
    FontF fontF = test.new FontF();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File infile = new File("C:\\Users\\Jake\\Sandbox\\test.jor.ildoc");
                ArrayList<FontF> fontStuff = new ArrayList<FontF>();
        try {
            FileReader in = new FileReader(infile);
            BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line;
            while (!((line = readFIle.readLine()).contains("<!Font Definitions,"))) {

        }
        int counter = 0;
        while (!((line = readFile.readLine()).compareTo("") == 0)) {
            String id,temp;
            id = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));
            id = id.trim();
            temp = line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 1);
            temp = temp.trim();
            temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 1);
            String[] array = temp.split(" ");
            fontStuff.add(fontF);
            fontStuff.get(counter).FontID = id;
            fontStuff.get(counter).FontFamily = array[0];
            fontStuff.get(counter).FontSize = array[1];
            if (array.length == 3) {
                fontStuff.get(counter).FontAttribute = array[2];
            } else {
                fontStuff.get(counter).FontAttribute = "Normal";
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fontStuff.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("FontID: " + fontStuff.get(i).FontAttribute);
        System.out.println("FontFamily: " + fontStuff.get(i).FontFamily);
        System.out.println("FontSize: " + fontStuff.get(i).FontSize);
        System.out.println("FontAttribute: " + fontStuff.get(i).FontAttribute);
        System.out.println();
    }
    readFile.close();
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And this was the second:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String FontID = "";
    String FontFamily = "";
    String FontSize = "";
    String FontAttribute = "";
    ArrayList<String> fontVariables = new ArrayList<String>();
    fontVariables.add(FontID);
    fontVariables.add(FontFamily);
    fontVariables.add(FontSize);
    fontVariables.add(FontAttribute);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fontStuff = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    File infile = new File("C:\\Users\\Jake\\Sandbox\\test.jor.ildoc");
    try {
        FileReader in = new FileReader(infile);
        BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        while (!((line = readFile.readLine()).contains("<!Font Definitions,"))) {

        }
        int counter = 0;
        while (!((line = readFile.readLine()).compareTo("") == 0)) {
            if (line.contains("=")) {
                String id,temp;
                id = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(" "));
                id = id.trim();
                temp = line.substring(line.indexOf("=") + 1);
                temp = temp.trim();
                temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 1);
                String[] array = temp.split(" ");
                fontStuff.add(fontVariables);
                fontStuff.get(counter).set(0, id);
                fontStuff.get(counter).set(1, array[0]);
                fontStuff.get(counter).set(2, array[1]);
                if (array.length==3) {
                    fontStuff.get(counter).set(3, array[2]);
                } else {
                    fontStuff.get(counter).set(3, "Normal");
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < fontStuff.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("FontID: " + fontStuff.get(i).get(0));
            System.out.println("FontFamily: " + fontStuff.get(i).get(1));
            System.out.println("FontSize: " + fontStuff.get(i).get(2));
            System.out.println("FontAttribute: " + fontStuff.get(i).get(3));
            System.out.println();
        }
        readFile.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

If someone could help me get it to display the information correctly, I would really appreciate the input. Currently, it's stuck displaying only the last font information 19 times (F38).

Comment: Why not use the `String` class's `split` function to split on " " from the get-go and use that to access each of your components. Then, rather than use an `ArrayList`, store your data in a `HashMap<String,ArrayList>`, where your key is the font ID, and the value is the array list containing the font information.

Comment: Can you please tell from where fontStuff is coming. There might be a problem with the implementation of that.

Comment: I'll have to try that. I realize this isn't well formatted code (sorry), I was just going to code it to work and then clean it up. Never used `HashMap`'s before, I'll have to look at those a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it in the first example. It's an ArrayList consisting of FontF classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same variable (`fontVariables`) to your `fontStuff` list. But Java only add a reference to the list, so you get a list referring many times to the same variable. That's the reason why you get many times the last font read.

To keep the list of all font, you must allocate a new `fontVariables` at each iteration in your loop.